# Add to vertical panel from bottom to top in gwt

Tags: gwt

I have a vertical panel in gwt and I want to add widgets into it from bottom to top.
In some reasons I want this.
Is that possible?
Actually I want to show results vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
insert(Widget w, int beforeIndex)
```

Here, for bottom to top, you need to set **beforeIndex** to **0**

Refer to [GWT Vertical Panel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalPanel.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think a best approach is to create your own VerticalPanel by creating a class that extends Composite, and implementing desired behavior.addToButtom() , addtoTop() ...